# What causes this code to work only on some compilers (UD?)?

Tags: c, compilation, undefined-behavior

In my code I had this line:

```
f(t->a, t->b, destroy(t));
```

Where `f` is a function, `t` is a pointer to a struct and `destroy` is a function which frees the pointer t and returns `NULL`. The code compiled and run successfully on some compilers (cc, gcc, clang on OS X and clang on Linux) as I expected - `t->a` and `t->b` were evaluated before freeing `t`. However, when compiling with cc/gcc on Linux I got a segmentation fault, as if I was trying to dereference null pointer. What causes that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Order of evaluation of arguments of a function call is uspecified. `destroy(t)` may evaluate first and `t` will be free and therefore `t->a` will invoke undefined behavior.

#### C11: 6.5.2.2 Function calls (p12):

> In the function call
>
> ```
> (*pf[f1()]) (f2(), f3() + f4())
> ```
>
> the functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` may be called in any order. [...]

Comment: In other words, the order depends completely on the compiler?

Comment: In theory, a compiler could have various order of arguments evaluation for different call sites of the same function.